# Avoid Exponent notation in Hadoop pig

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I want to avoid exponent notation in Hadoop Pig.
For ex.

My output is like

123,123123,3.8284426969382444E14

How can I avoid that exponent notation ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [BigDecimal.toPlainString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString%28%29):

> Returns a string representation of this BigDecimal without an exponent field.

**Example:**

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal("3.8284426969382444E14");
System.out.println(number.toPlainString());
```

Output:

```
382844269693824.44
```

Comment: There is also the option of using a DecimalFormat to directly format the double, but I think the BigDecimal solution is simpler for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the round-off error that Java does when a number gets very big. Can you post your code so I can take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the exponential notation create a custom `UDF` that returns the String representation of the double value as mentioned by Reimeus. E.g:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataType;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.schema.Schema;

public class DoubleConverter extends EvalFunc<String> {

    @Override
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            Double num = (Double) input.get(0);
            if (num == null) {
                return null;
            }

            BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(num);
            return bigDecimal.toPlainString();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("DoubleConverter error", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Schema outputSchema(Schema input) {
        return new Schema(new Schema.FieldSchema(null, DataType.CHARARRAY));
    }

}
```

Pack it in a jar to be able to use it in a Pig script:

```
register '/home/user/test/myjar.jar';
DEFINE convertDouble com.example.DoubleConverter();
A = load '/user/hadoop/store/sample/sample.txt' using PigStorage(',') as  
      (id1:int,id2:int,id3:double);
B = foreach A generate id1,id2, convertDouble(id3);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add the data type as long while retrieving the data from the flat file then you can avoid that.
e.g. 
records = LOAD '**FILE_NAME**' using PigStorage(',') as 
                        (d1:*chararray*,d2:*chararray*,d3:*chararray*,d4:***long***,
d5:***long***,d6:*chararray*,d7:*chararray*,d8:*chararray*,                 d9:***long***,d10:***long***,d11:***long***,d12:***long***);